# Install packages using PIP in Python 3.3 on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests, package

I have windows 7 with Python 3.3 installed. I also installed `pip` by referring to: 
https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation

I am facing issues with package installation-

If I run,

- `C:\Python33\Scripts> pip install requests`
  (OR)
- `C:\Python33\Scripts>pip install -U googlemaps`

It does not give any success message like

> 'the package is installed'.

It is basically not showing any error/success message. Please refer below screenshot -

[image]

How can I install packages using `pip`, or how do I know if I have successfully installed packages?

TIA,
Sanket.

Comment: You can use **pip show googlemaps**  to check whether the package is installed or use  **pip list**  to view all the installed packages.Use [offical-site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip) to install pip

Comment: Thanks Nitin, but no luck :( it isnt showing anything.

Comment: can you pls post a  screenshot of what are you getting on **pip install requests**

Comment: Just added a screenshot to the original post. the same is happening in case of pip install requests.

Comment: okay this weird . do u mind reinstalling [python3](https://www.python.org/) from scratch

Comment: Ahh ! Worked after reinstalling! Thank you very much, Nitin :)

Comment: I've made an answer as your problem is solved, so do mind closing the question @Sanket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pip show package_name` to check whether the package is installed or use the `pip list` to view all installed packages.

Please follow the [official website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) instruction to install pip or 
Try reinstalling [Python](https://www.python.org)